# Prove zeros of a complex polynomial lie inside a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

[Original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYIHP.jpg)

> $\quad13$. Prove that all the zeros of the
>   polynomial $x^{10}-5x^7+13x^3-27$
>   lie inside $\{z:|z|\le 4\}$. (Extra Credit:
>   Improve upon $4$ if you have time.)

I know this kind of question often uses trig inequality, and often plus something then minus it as a trick, but I really do not know how to determine what I should plus and minus, is there any rule for this kind of problem?
Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Rouche's theorem? If yes, have you tried applying it?

Comment: No, I did not learn that in class, but I will try to search it as your suggestion!

Comment: Given that you tagged it with complex analysis, which topic was this question posted in? While it is a direct application of Rouche's theorem, your instructor might want another approach.

Comment: this question is in my final review sheet, I guess it belongs to trig inequality

Comment: You can perfectly live without Rouche's theorem. It is a lemma useful once, in the proof of one theorem, and is mostly inadequate everywhere else. I wish complex analysis courses would stop programming students to believe that Rouche's theorem is the way to go to bound, locate, or count roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z$ be a root of this equation. Then

$$|z|^{10}=|z^{10}|= | 5z^7-13z^3+27| \leq 5|z|^7+13|z|^3+27$$

Let $x:= |z|$. Then $x \geq 0$ and 
$$x^{10} \leq 5x^7+13x^3+27\\
x^3\leq 5+13\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{27}{x^{7}}$$

Now, if you assume by contradiction that $x \geq 4$ then 
$$64=4^3 \leq x^3 \leq 5+13+27=45$$

Note that in the last step we only used $x \geq 4 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} \leq 1$ which can be improved quite a lot,for the extra credit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate

Comment: How do you go from $x^{10}  \leq 5x^7 + 13x^3 + 27$ to $x^3 \leq 5 + 13\frac 1{x^7} + \frac {27}{x^{10}}$? Didn't you divide by $x^7$ and then have $x^3 \leq 5 + \frac {13}{x^4} + \frac {27}{x^7}$?

Comment: @Bermudes typo, fixed. Ty

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that for $ |z| > 4$, $|5z^7 - 13z^3 + 27 | < |z^{10} |$.

Comment: Ok, let me try it! Thanks